# Select All checkBox's in List View on client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview in which I have a checkbox in the header. I want to select all checkboxes in the rows, if the header checkbox is checked/unchecked. How can I achieve this on the client side? Here is the ListView design code.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvTypes" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">
            <table id="DataTables_Table_0" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive dataTable" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
                <thead class="box-header well" style="font-size: 12px !important;">
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="text-align: center; width: 50px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="SNo: activate to sort column descending">S.No 
                        </th>
<th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="text-align: center; width: 188px;" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">Name  
                        </th>                                                    
<th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="text-align: center; width: 200px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged" Text="Action"/>
                        </th>
                        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="text-align: center; width: 188px;" aria-label="Employee ID: activate to sort column ascending">Desription 
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDelProjectType" Checked="false" runat="server" />
            <a class="iframe2 cboxElement" href='<%# ResolveUrl("./Admin_EditPage.aspx?editTemplateId="+ Eval("id").ToString() ) %>'>
                <img src="./images/file_edit.png" alt="Edit Type" width="20px" height="20px" />
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <%# Eval("title") %>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <%# Eval("description") %>
        </td>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your header Checkbox to this one. We don't need it to postback.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"  onchange="CheckAll(this);" Text="Action"/>
```

After doing this add following javascript in your  tag.

```
function CheckAll(checkid) {
            var updateButtons = $('#DataTables_Table_0 input[type=checkbox]');
            if ($(checkid).children().is(':checked')) {
                updateButtons.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("id") != $(checkid).children().attr("id")) {
                        $(this).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                updateButtons.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("id") != $(checkid).children().attr("id")) {
                        $(this).prop("checked", false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I keep getting the error "CS0103: The name "CheckBox1" does not exist in the current context. Although I have copied exact code from above for both CheckBox control and javascript function :S

Comment: Sorry for trouble, Actually **Checkbox1** is inside a **ListView** so it's obvious getting an context error if we use `$("#<%=CheckBox1.ClientID%>")` as referrence. I have edited my above code . please try this one, this might work.

Comment: Now I get the error on declaration of the checkBox .. it says "Expected ')'

Comment: @WQad : I have did some modification to my code and tested them it's now working fine but i have encountered a minor issue . For the first time it is not selecting all check boxes until Uncheck it and check again. I'll correct this code and update edited code as soon as i get some spare time.

Comment: Excellent it works perfectly fine. Accepting your answer. but one more little question. is there any way to check/uncheck this header checkbox from server side as well? for example if rows in listview are deleted after checking this checkbox, the state of the checkbox should be reset

Comment: Not sure, never did it though reason being doing programmaticaly would cause a postback. It not use a update panel I have to reload the page again. Theoretically it may possible all we have to do is to run a foreach for n number of tr and corresponding to that we need to find **cbldelProjectType** checked and set it's checked property.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("onload", function(){
   document.getElementById("DataTables_Table_0_wrapper").querySelector("thead").querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").addEventListener("click", checkTheBoxes, false);
}, false);

  function checkTheBoxes()
  {
     var checkIt;

     if (this.checked)
     {
        checkIt = true;
     }
     else
     {
        checkIt = false;
     }

     var checkboxes = document.getElementById("DataTables_Table_0_wrapper").querySelector("tbody").querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
     Array.prototype.map.call(checkboxes, function(element){
         element.setAttribute("checked", checkIt);
     });
  }
```

This should do it:

It starts with adding a click event to your checkbox in the header. When clicked it checks if the box is ticked or not using `this.checked`. It then select your checkboxes within the listview table's body. The table itself wrapped in a div with an id. Select all elements in the `tbody` using querySelectorAll, that are a checkbox. Then iterate over them using `Array.prototype.map`, checking or unchecking them one by one.

Comment: I put this code u provided in <script> part of my Asp:Content (where other functions are) but it does not seem to work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Does it throw an exception of some kind? Is that script block before or after the listview?

Comment: I have two Asp:Content in my page. First one is for scripts for validation and the second one has the UI elements including the above code of ListView that I posted. I added the code u provided in the first Asp:Content where all the validation functions are

Comment: @WQad then we need to wait for page completion. Updated my code,